# Find latest modified file information in PowerShell

Tags: powershell-3.0, last-modified

I run this code:

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\Test Folder' | Where {$_.LastWriteTime} | select -last 1
```

And I get back **Mode, LastWriteTime, Length, and Name** of the last modified file - great!

I'm trying to get the username of the file's owner as well.

I've added this code:

```
| ForEach-Object {Get-Acl $_.FullName}
```

Which returns **Path, Owner, Access** for the file.

How can I display **LastWriteTime, and Owner** to be the only objects shown in the output?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Are you sure that what you are trying to do is not the following?

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\Test Folder' | Sort {$_.LastWriteTime} | select -last 1
```

You can try this:

```
$c = Get-ChildItem 'C:\Test Folder' | Sort {$_.LastWriteTime} | select -last 1 | foreach {$a=$_;$b=Get-Acl $_.FullName; Add-Member -InputObject $b -Name "LastWriteTime" -MemberType NoteProperty -Value $a.LastWriteTime;$b}
$c.LastWriteTime
```

Answer (score 3):

So the select will allow you to just get the properties you are interested in.

So a few things to do:

1. Figure out what properties you could select from

   ```bsh
   Get-ChildItem | Get-Member -membertype properties
   ```
2. Once you know the properties just add to the select in your original statement

   ```bsh
   Get-ChildItem'c:\test folder' | where {$_.lastwritetime} | select -last 1 | `
   foreach { write-host $_.lastwritetime ((get-ACL).owner)}
   ```

Finally, don't be afraid of the [Get-Help](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/Get-Help) command.